# Given std::map with pointers to a non-constant class for keys, how to access it via a pointer to const?

Tags: c++, stl, constants, std, stdmap

There is a map of a type `std::map<A*, B*> m` that describes correspondence between objects of type A and objects of type B.
There is a function `int exctractInfo(const A *a)` that needs to read some info from an object of type `B` which corresponds to a given object of type `A`. This is a semantically constant operation, nothing needs to be changed, we just need to read some info, but the problem is that C++ **doesn't allow access to map `m` via a pointer to const**.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <map>

class A {

};

class B {
    int info_;

public:
    int info() const { return info_; }
};

std::map<A*, B*> m;

int exctractInfo(const A *a) {
    auto it = m.find(a);
    if (it != m.end() && it->second) {
       return it->second->info();
    }
    return -1;
}

int main () {
    return 0;
}
```

[Here's a link](http://cpp.sh/7moik) to online compiler for this code. I get the following error:

> error: invalid conversion from 'const A*' to 'std::map::key_type {aka A*}' [-fpermissive]

Now I see two solutions:

1. Rewrite the type `std::map<A*, B*>` as `std::map<const A*, B*>`, as I have access to the source code, but that is basically a type of a library object, and a lot of code depend on it, so it will have to be changed, thus changing the map type is really undesirable;
2. Use const cast like this: `auto it = m.find(const_cast<A*>(a));`, which also doesn't seem like a good solution, more of a hack.

I don't understand why it doesn't work. If the key is `std::string` or `int`, for example, I can access `std::map<std::string, B*>` via `const std::string` just fine. So what's wrong with my example? Is there a proper way to handle this situation?

Comment: But you don't have a const pointer, you have a pointer to const. i.e. the map will handle `A * const` just fine, but not a `A const *`. My guess is `extractInfo` could take a `A * const` instead.

Comment: The third solution is to use a transparent comparator: `std::map<A*, B*, std::less<>> m;`

Comment: @cigien, yes, you're right, sorry, I named it wrong, it's a pointer to const of course. The problem is that I get those pointers from a code that I can't change, so even if I change signature of ```extractInfo```, I'd still have to discard const qualifier at some point. The point is that object A is not allowed to be changed, that's why it's const. But the ```const *A``` and ```*A``` will hold the same address, so it's the same key, so technically it should be enough the access a value of a map without changing anything along the way.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, because I didn't want to mess around with the old code where this map is declared, and also because it would mean changing a lot of code that uses this map in a project. Plus I read somewhere that making a key const is moot, since, as you said, keys are immutable anyway. But now I see how it can come back and bite you later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why it doesn't work. If the key is std::string or int, for example, I can access std::map via const std::string just fine. So what's wrong with my example?

Because there is a significant difference btw constant pointer to non constant data and non constant pointer to constant data. Your map has first as a key, you try to pass second. So if you are pre C++14 only viable solution would be `const_cast` I am afraid (beside changing key type of course). If you can use C++14 or later then "transparent comparison" is available as stated in `std::map::find()` [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find). For it to work you would need to declare your map like this:

```
std::map<A*, B*,std::less<>> m;
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/f15yGQ)

Comment: It does seem unfortunate that these antics are required, given that a conversion from `A*` to `const A*` ought to be value-transparent and incur literally zero runtime cost :(

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I don't think that transparent comparison would invoke runtime cost as that code is templatized.

Comment: I didn't say it would!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings then I do not quite understand your concern. Conversion from const to non-const is a dangerous operation and so not allowed to be done implicitly. You can use `const_cast` to override that and that would not have any runtime const. OP does not like casting so there is alternative solution for that.

Comment: Conversion from non-const to const is just fine, value-transparent and zero cost. `A* ptr1 = foo(); const A* ptr2 = ptr1;` So it's a shame `find` can't do this for us when the map key is `ptr2` and the input is `ptr1`. We need "antics" like explicitly creating a transparent comparator that IMO ought to be implicit.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings actually `std::map::find()` can do it inside, we cannot bind `ptr1` to a method which argument  type is `ptr2`, But that is not `find()` problem but language.

Comment: I don't think that argument tracks. It works just fine when you define a transparent comparator, so clearly `find()` can accept the argument we want to give it.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings "so clearly find() can accept the argument we want to give it" No it cannot, in that case that an overload which is a different method.

Comment: I'm aware that it doesn't work. I'm saying it would be nice if it did, and that it would be possible to make it work. Not sure why this is so controversial!